# Where do I put .xcolortheme files in Xcode when there is no ~/Library/Application Support/Xcode/Color Themes folder?

Tags: xcode, xcode3.2

I'm just getting started with Mac and iPhone development, and naturally my first step is to change the color theme.  I've found a theme I like [here](http://tracesof.blogspot.com/2009/03/zenburn-color-theme-for-xcode.html), but I can't find the folder they reference in my `~/Library/Application Support/` folder.  How can I install these files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`~/Library/Application Support/Xcode/Color Themes`. If any of those folders don't exist, create them.